# Find out which Content Type a field is associated with using PowerShell

Tags: list, powershell, content-type, sharepoint-fields

I have added two Content Types to a List some of the Fields exist in both content types so I have got duplicate fields. The field which is added by the new Content Type is empty.

Now I want to iterate through all items and copy data from fields associated with the old content type to the fields which are associated with the new Content Type.

How Can I find out which field is associated to which content type using PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

This powershell script will show the name of all content types that contains a field by its name.

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://YourSiteURL
$web = $site.RootWeb

$columnName = "Your_Site_Column_Name"
$guid = $web.fields[$columnName].id 

$contentTypes = $web.AvailableContentTypes
for ($x=0; $x -lt $contentTypes.Count; $x++) 
{
  for ($y=0; $y -lt $contentTypes[$x].Fields.Count; $y++) 
  {
    if ($contentTypes[$x].Fields[$y].id -eq $guid)
    {
      Write-Host $contentTypes[$x].Name " contains column " $columnName
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do the same as above.

```
$fieldName = <Internal Field Name>
$web = Get-SPWeb <Site URL>

$field = $web.Fields[$fieldName]
$web.AvailableContentTypes | where{$_.Fields | where{$_.ID -eq $field.ID}} | Select ID, Name, Group
```